# ¿Cómo copiar una matriz?

Tags: java

No puedo copiar una matriz en un método de un archivo. Sin embargo, creo una clase de matriz con un método de copia.

Aqui, en `rotateNinetyDegree.java` intento copiar la matriz `matrix`

```
public class rotateNinetyDegrees{

    public static void rotateNinetyDegrees(int[][] matrix){
        //use a copy
        Matrix copy = new Matrix(matrix);
        //update by line
        for(int i=0;i<matrix.size;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<matrix.size;j++){
                matrix[i][j]=copy[matrix.size+1-j][j];
            }
        }

        system.out.println(matrix);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){


        m = new matrix(10);

        rotateNinetyDegrees(m); 

    }

}
```

Aqui, en `Matrix.java`, tengo el constructador y el método de copia :

```
class Matrix{

    Matrix(int n){
        this.size = n;
        this.matrix=new int[n][n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
            }           
        }
    }

    public Matrix(Matrix another){
        this.matrix = another.matrix;
    }

}
```

Y los errores son :

> ```
> mike@mike-thinks:~/CrackingTheCodingInterview$ javac rotateNinetyDegrees.java rotateNinetyDegrees.java:5:
> error: no suitable constructor found for Matrix(int[][])
> Matrix copy = new Matrix(matrix);
>               ^
>     constructor Matrix.Matrix(int) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; int[][] cannot be converted to int)
>     constructor Matrix.Matrix(Matrix) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; int[][] cannot be converted to Matrix)
> rotateNinetyDegrees.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
>       for(int i=0;i<matrix.size;i++){
>                           ^
>   symbol:   variable size
>   location: variable matrix of type int[][]
> rotateNinetyDegrees.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
>           for(int j=0;j<matrix.size;j++){
>                               ^
>   symbol:   variable size
>   location: variable matrix of type int[][]
> rotateNinetyDegrees.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
>               matrix[i][j]=copy[matrix.size+1-j][j];
>                                       ^
>   symbol:   variable size
>   location: variable matrix of type int[][]
> rotateNinetyDegrees.java:9: error: array required, but Matrix found
>               matrix[i][j]=copy[matrix.size+1-j][j];
>                                ^
> rotateNinetyDegrees.java:13: error: package system does not exist
>       system.out.println(matrix);
>             ^
> rotateNinetyDegrees.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
>       m = new Matrix(10);
>       ^
>   symbol:   variable m
>   location: class rotateNinetyDegrees
> rotateNinetyDegrees.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
>       rotateNinetyDegrees(m); 
>                           ^
>   symbol:   variable m
>   location: class rotateNinetyDegrees
> ./Matrix.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
>       this.size = n;
>           ^
>   symbol: variable size
> ./Matrix.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
>       this.matrix=new int[n][n];
>           ^
>   symbol: variable matrix
> ./Matrix.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
>               matrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
>               ^
>   symbol:   variable matrix
>   location: class Matrix
> ./Matrix.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
>       this.matrix = another.matrix;
>           ^
>   symbol: variable matrix
> ./Matrix.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
>       this.matrix = another.matrix;
>                            ^
>   symbol:   variable matrix
>   location: variable another of type Matrix
> 13 errors
> ```

Parece que no puedo copiar porque dice :

```
constructor Matrix.Matrix(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int[][] cannot be converted to int)
    constructor Matrix.Matrix(Matrix) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int[][] cannot be converted to Matrix)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu primer error esta en este método

```
Matrix(int n){
        this.size = n;
        this.matrix=new int[n][n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
            }           
        }
    }
```

Ya que es un constructor debes de definir el tipo de acceso en este caso debe de quedar como:

```
public Matrix(int n)
```

El segundo error es que la variable `matrix` que utilizas aquí:

```
this.matrix=new int[n][n];
```

nunca fue declarada por lo que necesitas declararla globalmente:

```
int matrix[][];
```

de esta manera